# Use result of publisher in map of another publisher

Tags: swift, mvvm, combine, flatmap, publisher

As example I have a basic published value like

```swift
@Published var value: String
```

I have want to validates this value of my form to give my user an output. For that I will use Combine in my MVVM project.

Now this type of value needs to be validated against my REST API. For my REST API I already have a method to get my results of my like `getFirstMailboxRedirectFromAPI` which returns `AnyPublisher<MailboxAPIResponse, APIError>`. MailboxAPIResponse is a decodable object for the api response. So if I just want to display the result, I create a subscriber with `.sink` add the result to a variable which will be shown in a view. So good so far. Now my problem:

As described in the first section my value is already a Publisher (because of @Published), where I can do some `.map` stuff for validation with it and returning true or false if everything is fine or not.

So to validate my published value I need to call my other Publisher which uses the API to check if the value already exists. But I don't know how this should work.

This is my code so far but this doesn't work. But this shows you my idea how it should work.

```swift
private var isMailboxRedirectNameAvailablePublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
    $mailboxRedirectName
        .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: RunLoop.main)
        .setFailureType(to: Error.self)
        .flatMap { name in
            self.getFirstMailboxRedirectFromAPI(from: name, and: self.domainName)
                .map { apiResponse in
                    return apiResponse.response.data.count == 0
                }
        }
        .eraseToAnyPublisher()
}
```

So in result the publisher should use the redirectName to call the API and the API gives me the result if the mailbox already exists, then returns a boolean, if it's existing or not.

How can I nest multiple publishers and use the result of the API publisher in my published value publisher?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I simplified a little but key take aways are 1) use switchToLatest to flatten a Publisher of Publishers if you want the operation to restart (flatMap is a merge, so events could arrive out of order).  2) You need to handle the failure types and make sure an inner Publisher never fails or the outer publisher will also complete.

```
final class M: ObservableObject {
  @Published var mailboxRedirectName: String = ""
  private var isMailboxRedirectNameAvailablePublisher: AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> {
      $mailboxRedirectName
        .debounce(for: 0.5, scheduler: DispatchQueue.main)
          .map { [weak self] name -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Never> in
            guard let self = self else { return Just(false).eraseToAnyPublisher() }
            return self
              .getFirstMailboxRedirectFromAPI(from: name)
              .replaceError(with: false)
              .eraseToAnyPublisher()
          }
          .switchToLatest()
          .eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }

  func getFirstMailboxRedirectFromAPI(from name: String) -> AnyPublisher<Bool, Error> {
    Just(true).setFailureType(to: Error.self).eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! But why I have to do it this way?